# Why is my overloaded << operator not outputting the last line?

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,SparseMatrix& m)
{
RowNode* rowPoint = m.rowFront;
Node* point = rowPoint->firstInRow;


while(rowPoint != NULL)
    {
    while (point != NULL)
        {
        os << point->row;
        os << ' ';
        os << point->column;
        os << ' ';
        os << point->data;
        os << endl;
        point = point->right; 
        }
    rowPoint = rowPoint->nextRow;
    point = rowPoint->firstInRow;
    }

os << "0 0 0" << endl;

return os;
}
```

When I try to run this in my program, the list is out put completely right, but the final "0 0 0" line never shows up. I've tried formatting it differently, placing it in an if statement at the end of the larger while loop, I've even tried outputting a bunch more than just the "0 0 0" to see if it could print anything, but no dice.

If anyone needs to look at more code I'd be happy to provide it!

Comment: According to your code, if `rowPoint` is NULL or `point` is NULL, no printing will occur.  I recommend using a debugger and *watching* those two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, when you reach the last element, `rowPoint` will be set to NULL with `rowPoint = rowPoint->nextRow;`

Unfortunately, you dereference this null pointer before checking if it's NULL, in the next statement:

```
point = rowPoint->firstInRow;
```

This causes UB.

To solve it change slightly your code:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,SparseMatrix& m)
{
RowNode* rowPoint = m.rowFront;

while(rowPoint != NULL)
    {
    Node* point = rowPoint->firstInRow;  // here you're sure not to dereference NULL ptr
    while (point != NULL)
        {
        ...
        point = point->right; 
        }
    rowPoint = rowPoint->nextRow;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I was just typing up an answer to my own question because I figured that out right after posting this...

Answer (score 1):

```
rowPoint = rowPoint->nextRow;
point = rowPoint->firstInRow;
```

`rowPoint` will eventually return a `nullptr`, and `point` will use that invalid pointer to access `firstInRow`, which will make your app crash and the code `os << "0 0 0" << endl;` will never be executed. Or perhaps `nextRow` never returns null (therefore your loop never ends).

Solution:

```
while (rowPoint != NULL)
{
    point  = rowPoint->firstInRow;

    while (point != NULL)
    {
        os << point->row;
        os << ' ';
        os << point->column;
        os << ' ';
        os << point->data;
        os << endl;
        point = point->right;
    }

    rowPoint = rowPoint->nextRow;
}
```